# PyQt kled in Unity enviornmet?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I'm trying to use the python kled module that's featured in QT Designer under ubuntu 13.10 Unity. Is it possible to use with Unity or will i need to use a KDE environment?

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see what happens?

Comment: i can't figure out how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use KLed in my PyQt4 gui. Originally it was developed in the Kubuntu environment, so this wasn't an issue, but we ended up having to move to Unity (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS). In order to still use KLed I found that I needed to apt-get install the python libraries from kde (didn't want to install Kubuntu as it interfered with operation).

The fix was:
sudo apt-get install python-kde4

SO the summary answer is:
Yes, you can use KLed in Unity, as long as you have the libraries installed.